# getting the rowindex of gridview based on the label control value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `label control` on my page and beneath the `label control` there is a `Gridview`.The value that exists in the label control also exists in the `Gridview`. The label control has value like this

```
3244|Yellow Ink| Test Link
```

In the gridview, I have a value 3244 too

```
3244    yello Ink   Test Link
3255    Green Link  Test2
```

I want the **row Index of 3244** in my code behind as soon as the **page loads**. Is their any way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what type of data source you have, one way of doing it would be with LINQ like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Fetch the text from your label. (I'm assuming that you have only one label with the text "3244|Yellow Ink| Test Link".
    string text = Label1.Text;

    // Find the first row or return null if not found.
    var resultRow = GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().FirstOrDefault(row =>
    {
        // Get the id (that I'm guessing is the first (0-index) column/cell)
        var id = row.Cells[0].Text;

        // Return true/false if the label text starts with the same id.
        return text.StartsWith(id);
    });

    if (resultRow != null)
    {
        var index = resultRow.RowIndex;
    }
}
```

A shorter version would look like this:

```
var resultRow = GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
    .FirstOrDefault(r => text.StartsWith(r.Cells[0].Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected void btnJobAppSelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewJobApplications.Rows)
    {

        int rowIndex = ((sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow).RowIndex;

        LinkButton btnJobAppSelected = (LinkButton)GridViewJobApplications.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("btnJobAppSelected");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your page load after populating gridView, you can do that like this:

```
   String searchValue = "3244 ";
    int rowIndex = -1;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewID.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[0].Text.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
        {
            rowIndex = row.RowIndex;
            break;
        }
    }
    int YourIndex = rowIndex;
```